# curve ball trajectory in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, math, animation

i have a JavaScript function that i wrote that makes a red css ball travel randomly across the screen. the problem is, is that since it goes directly from one position to another, it does not look that smooth.  making it do a curve when it changes positions would probably make this smoother. based on the code provided, what would be a good way of doing this?

```
$('#menu_button4').click(function(){
    $('#ball').show();
    cake = function(a,b,u) {return (1-u) * a + u * b;};
    draw_pos = function(element, property1, property2, start, end, duration) {
      var interval = 10;
      var steps = duration/interval;
      var step_u = 1.0/steps;
      var u = 0.0;
      var theInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if (u >= 1.0){ clearInterval(theInterval) }
        var s = parseInt(cake(start.s, end.s, u));
        var d = parseInt(cake(start.d, end.d, u));
        var x_pos = s+'%';
        var y_pos = d+'%';
        el.style.setProperty(property1, x_pos);
        el.style.setProperty(property2, y_pos);
        u += step_u;
      }, interval);
    };
    el = document.getElementById('ball');
    property1 = 'top';
    property2 = 'left';
    startdeg_1 = {s:'0', d:'0'};
    enddeg_1 = {s:Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), d:Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)};
    enddeg_2 = {s:Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), d:Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)};
    enddeg_3 = {s:Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), d:Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)};
    enddeg_4 = {s:Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), d:Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)};
    enddeg_5 = {s:'40', d:'25'};
    enddeg_6 = {s:'20', d:'20'};
    draw_pos(el, property1, property2, startdeg_1, enddeg_1, 80);
    setTimeout(function(){draw_pos(el, property1, property2, enddeg_1, enddeg_2, 80)}, 700);
    setTimeout(function(){draw_pos(el, property1, property2, enddeg_2, enddeg_3, 80)}, 1400);
    setTimeout(function(){draw_pos(el, property1, property2, enddeg_3, enddeg_4, 80)}, 2050);
    setTimeout(function(){draw_pos(el, property1, property2, enddeg_4, enddeg_5, 80)}, 2650);
    setTimeout(function(){draw_pos(el, property1, property2, enddeg_5, enddeg_6, 80)}, 3200);
  });
```

Comment: Could [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jfk63/) be of assistance?

Comment: The first step is to rewrite this from scratch, instead of adding on top of this unreadable and messy code. But it would be easier if you provided a working example or explained what exactly the movement should be.

Comment: When you say 'smooth', do you mean smooth, as in not jerky or made up of discontinuous movement. Or do you mean smooth, as in it looks polished, refined and smooth? Perhaps you mean something else altogether? Are you interested in simulating the effect of gravity, or would you like movement to be slowest at the start/end of movement, with the highest velocity occuring in the middle of flight (ease-out and ease-in) At times in programming, a single semi-colon makes all the difference. Discussions about programming sometimes need to be equally precise. :)

Comment: this unreadable and messy code is what i wrote

Comment: and alix that looks pretty interesting. for this i would have to apply something like that in between each transition